# Find the word in a string after a list of words

Tags: python, string, split, token

my friend and i are studying words and their meaning and i need help trying to get the word that we want to learn about. I have a list of words that we type into the command line that will tell the computer we want the meaning or history of the word we want. My problem is finding out which word we typed in. here is my code so far:

```
Meaning = {"Meaning", "define", "history"}
text1  = raw_input("Text: ")
tokens = commands.lower().split()
if Meaning.intersection(tokens):
    #Here is the problem, because i don't know what word we might type
    #so i need it to check the word after the Meaning. How can i do this?
```

I am using the program to type into a website and get information on the word, so i can't add the word and the definition because it would be too hard to do every word i know. How can i get the word after the meaning?, Thank you.

Comment: "my friend and i are studying words and their meaning" - is that something you're actually doing, or a framing device used to introduce your homework assignment and give a motivation for the things you'll implement? We need to know whether to point you to english.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your dictionary as set of pairs.

```
terms = {'word1': 'meaning', 'word2': 'othermeaning'}

print terms['word1']
```

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to add some information, I am using this to search a site that shows the definition and history of the word. I have it type the word into the website and find the word. The reason why this would not work is because we would use any word in the dictionary, which would be hard to put every word and its meaning into the program.

Comment: @user3299646: Why are you using a command line interface for this? Why not browse the website with a web browser?

Comment: The program can go a lot more faster than what i can search. I can search 5 words within the time it takes me to look up one on the browser.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do. Be explicit what you want the program to do. One thing that you might be running into is that the term "dictionary" is a data type in python, and it could be that you are talking about the merriam-webster variety.